# How can I test resp.getOutputStream()

Tags: java, servlets, mockito

I have servlet which I want to tested. I'd like to test doGet by Mockito.
In main code info from srvlet go to page /json by PrintWriter.
In my test I'd like to have file where I'll have my test info.And i can't test PrintWriter ( I don't understand how)

Instead of PrintWriter in test i tried use

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pw  =new PrintWriter(sw);
when(new PrintWriter(resp.getOutputStream())).thenReturn(pw);
```

This is my Servlet doGEt

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/json");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(resp.getOutputStream());
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(list);
        writer.append(jsonString);
        writer.flush();
    }
```

This is my test which doesn't work

```
@Test
    public void whenShouldCheckJsonSrevlet() throws ServletException, IOException {
        String fileWay = "D:\\CODE_WORK\\JAVA\\java-a-to-z\\lesson8Aplication\\src\\main\\java\\persistent\\test.txt";
        final JSONControllers servlet = new JSONControllers();
        HttpServletRequest req = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        HttpServletResponse resp = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileWay));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileWay));
        when(new PrintWriter(resp.getOutputStream())).thenReturn(writer);
        when(req.getReader()).thenReturn(reader);
        servlet.doGet(req,resp);
        servlet.doPost(req,resp);
    }

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Writer.<init>(Writer.java:88)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.<init>(OutputStreamWriter.java:109)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:148)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:131)
    at servlets.JSONControllersTest.whenShouldCheckJsonSrevlet(JSONControllersTest.java:62)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the object 'list', you are passing in the mapper's writeValueAsString? And which line is 62 of JSONControllersTest.java?

Answer (score 0):

```
 private ConcurrentHashMap<UUID, User> list = new ConcurrentHashMap<UUID, User>();
    public JSONControllers() {
        DbLocationStore db = DbLocationStore.getInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i < db.size(); i++) {
            list.put(generateID(),db.findById(String.valueOf(i)));
        }
    }
```

How it works. I have database. And form List from data and convert it to JSON
For today I solve my issue like this:

Before

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/json");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(resp.getOutputStream());
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(list);
        writer.append(jsonString);
        writer.flush();
    }
```

After

```
 @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/json");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(list);
        resp.getWriter().write(jsonString);
        resp.getWriter().flush();
    }
```

But I still interesting how orgonize test with this
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(resp.getOutputStream());

Answer (score 0):

And for current my test seems like this:

```
@Test

public void whenShouldCheckJsonSrevlet() throws ServletException, IOException {
    String fileWay = "D:\\CODE_WORK\\JAVA\\java-a-to-z\\lesson8Aplication\\src\\main\\java\\persistent\\test.txt";
    final JSONControllers servlet = new JSONControllers();
    HttpServletRequest req = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse resp = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileWay));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileWay));
    when(resp.getWriter()).thenReturn(writer);
    when(req.getReader()).thenReturn(reader);
    servlet.doGet(req,resp);
    servlet.doPost(req,resp);
}
```